# rewinding indexes of a polygon

Tags: opengl, maya, 3dsmax, fbx

I am reading my vertices,normals and indices from fbx files which are exported by maya and 3dsmax. When I apply the transformation, all the objects are in their correct position even the animations work fine. However at some meshes, normals are inverse and index orders are anti clockwise which I confirmed this by disabling culling. I realized that some objects had negative scaling, so I recursively calculated sign of the scale for each object by also reaching to their parent's scaling and rewinded those produced negative scale and mirrored their normals around origin. While this worked for 1-2 objects, this time some of the correct objects looked wrong. So I guess I need another criteria to decide which objects/meshes to rewind.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your FBX files to see if the `NormalsW` attributes of your meshes predict the winding errors (or if the combination of `NormalsW` and the original art package's handedness: max and maya are reversed relative to each other).  `NormalsW` should always be 1 or -1.